# What does following precompilation mean?

Tags: c++, precompile

Confronted with a C++ project recently and frequently see following precompilation code:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define __attribute__(x)
#endif
```

So in a general way what it is used for ?

Comment: At first that means, that code which uses attributes will compile and silently fail later! If attributes like pack and alignment is needed by the code and simply ignored by defining a empty macro, the result will be broken at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`__attribute__` is a special keyword supported e.g. by gcc, to specify things like alignment.

The given statement adds an *empty* `#define` for `__attribute__`  so that it is deleted by the pre processor when `_WIN32` is defined. This is e.g. required, if the compiler does not support `__attribute__`.

**EDIT**

A macro could have e.g. the following form:

```
#define DOUBLE(x) (x*2)
```

So if you would write `DOUBLE(4)` in your source it would be expanded/replace by the preprocessor to `(4*2)` before it is passed to the compiler. If omit the part to which it should be expanded, it would be expanded to an empty string.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes that's true, is changed it to `things like`.

Comment: Furthermore what does the `x` in parenthesis mean ?

Comment: @Finley it is just a _argument_ for the macro. Added an edit.

Comment: @Ron If `_WIN32` is defined then the `__attribute__` is _ignored_, because it is replace by an empty string in the preprocessing step.

Answer (score 2):

I'll just add a bit of background to the first answer from @t.niese

`__attribute__` is an extension in GCC and some other compilers (clang, Intel). It performs much the same job as `#pragma`. However, `#pragma` does have one major drawback: you can't use them in macros, since they get processed before macros.

So `__attribute__` was added, but with compilers that don't support it you need a workaround as already described in the comments and answer.

C99 and C++11 add `_Pragma` which can be used in a macro. I don't yet see it being used much. That's a bit of a shame as it does promise to be a portable solution to this issue.